# asp.net get values from few textFields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a problem to collect the values in my text fields .
in each row on my screen i have a text field and the user should be add values there (you can see it from the picture)

[exaple of my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTNQG.png)

this is my html code:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BarCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Profit)
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                        Amount:
                        <input type="text" id="amountTag" name="Amount" maxlength="2" placeholder="0" size="4" runat="server" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

}
```

and my code is

```
  // POST: User/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            /*Update the Database*/
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            string x = Request.Form["amountTag"];
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

this code always get Null and i don't have idea why

Comment: Nested forms is not a good idea - you can create `Amount` property, use `for` loop and bind it like `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item[i].Name)`, then add your viewmodel class as POST action parameter.

Comment: please give some example for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section will create a form inside existing form (nested forms), which is not a good way to bind the textbox:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Amount:
    <input type="text" id="amountTag" name="Amount" maxlength="2" placeholder="0" size="4" runat="server" />
</form>
```

The correct way should be like this:

1) Create an `int` property of `Amount` in the same viewmodel class as `BarCode`, `Name` and `Profit` properties has.

```
public class ViewModelName
{
    // required unique key for each rows
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other 3 properties here

    [DisplayName("Amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

2) Bind the model inside view with HTML helpers using `for` loop. Here you should add `TextBoxFor` helper for `Amount` property to let user input numeric value with HTML attributes you have previously:

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModelClassName>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BarCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Profit)
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Id)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].BarCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Profit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @* Amount *@
                    @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Amount)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Amount, new { maxlength = 2, ... })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

3) Make sure that action method decorated with `HttpPostAttribute` has list of viewmodel class as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<ViewModelName> model)
{
    try
    {
        // example to select all amount values
        var x = model.Select(x => x.Amount).ToList();

        // do something

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch 
    {
        // error handling

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

From this point, your model binding should working fine.

Related issue: [Need to pass a List<model> to the Http Post in a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163281/need-to-pass-a-listmodel-to-the-http-post-in-a-controller)